# Como iniciar um código Python de maneira correta

Tags: python

Eu ainda estou aprendendo Python e uma vez eu vi um cara começando um código Python com alguma coisa `____init___`, com um `if` `___init___ ... == True`. Eu perguntei para ele o porquê ele começava o código de tal maneira, ele me disse que esse era o jeito certo. Enfim, segue algumas duvidas

- O que significa `____init___`?
- Por que usar `____init___`?
- Quanto usar e quando não usar?

Comment: Pode verificar a resposta dada e certificar-se que está perguntando o certo? `__init__` e `__name__` são coisas completamente distintas.

Answer (score 2):

Você quer dizer este teste?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # faz algo
```

O que este teste determina é se a execução está acontecendo no **escopo principal**, ou seja, é o script que foi diretamente executado a partir da linha de comando (ou do menu gráfico).

Este teste é util quando você quer que o script possa ser importado com um **módulo** (caso em que o teste acima retornará Falso) mas também possa ser executado diretamente. (Como um módulo puro só define funções e classes, ele normalmente não faz nada mesmo que seja executado diretamente.)

Então, não tem "certo" ou "errado", pode ser uma prática interessante encapsular o código desse jeito para que um script seja "modularizado" facilmente, mas um script que sempre vá ser executado diretamente no futuro previsível não precisa disso.